# OC4J instance, form builder error

Tags: oracle, oc4j

After initialized OC4J I run form and i get this error :

configFileName: D:\DevSuitHome_1/forms/server/formsweb.cfg
testMode: false

anyone knows how to solve this error ?

Comment: what's the full error?

Comment: Have you looked at `formsweb.cfg` to see if there is a line with `testMode: false`? If there is a line with `testMode: false`, perhaps changing it to `testMode: true` will solve the problem.

Comment: I checked that, there is nothign like testmode .

Comment: @mikrimouse I wish there was, sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

in this URL C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms\server\formsweb.cfg 
by changing this

baseHTMLjinitiator=basejini.htm

to this

baseHTMLjinitiator=basejpi.htm